# Conditions for the product of two topologies to be a topology

Tags: general-topology

Take two topological spaces $(X,T_{X})$ and $(Y,T_{Y})$. What are the necessary conditions on $(X,T_{X})$ and $(Y,T_{Y})$ such that $$T_{1} := \{A \times B\mid A \in T_{X},B \in T_{Y}\}$$  ia a topology on $X\times Y$ and $$T_{2} := \{U \subseteq X \mid X \backslash U \text{ is infinite}\} \cup \{\emptyset,X\}$$ is a topology on $X$.

Comment: The elements of $T_2$ are not subsets of $X\times Y$, so that $T_2$ is not a topology of the product (but perhaps a topology of $X$ itself).

Comment: $T_1$ is a topology on $X \times Y$ whenever $T_X$ is a topology on $X$ and $T_Y$ is a topology on $Y$. About $T_2$, you really must check that; it can't be what you're looking for...

Comment: @amrsa $T_{1}$ isn't true for the axiom of unions and $T_{2}$ isn't true for  the axiom of intersections, so we need to impose conditions to respect these

Comment: Sorry, you're right about $T_1$. That family of sets is **a basis** for a topology on $X \times Y$, not the topology itself.

Comment: About $T_2$ I probably didn't see you edit of the question. Before that, it was hopeless...

Comment: And maybe in $T_2$ it should be $X \setminus U$ is finite? Otherwise, it will never work, because for $X \setminus U$ to be infinite, $X$ must be infinite, and then for each $x \in X$, since $X \setminus \{x\}$ is infinite, $\{x\}$ is open. But then it's the discrete topology and all subsets are open, in contradiction with the definition.

Comment: This time the question isn't wrong. I think that for $T_{2}$ to be a topology, $X$ needs to be finite, otherwise it will go against the definition, as you said.

Comment: Precisely. However, if $X$ is finite, then there is no $U \subseteq X$ such that $X \setminus U$ is infinite. Even $X$ and $\varnothing$ won't be open, which is a contradiction. That's why I suspect it must be something different, such as $U$ such that $X \setminus U$ is finite.

Comment: Consider $X$ finite, $X \backslash U$ is not infinite. Thus $X \backslash U = \emptyset$ or $X \backslash U = X$. Thus, $U = X$ or
$U = \emptyset$. Hence $T_{2}$ is the indiscrete topology with $X$ finite.

Comment: Yes, those don't have to follow the rule. I overlooked your new edit. Maybe it's it then...

Answer (score 0):

As discussed, if X is finite, $T_2$ is indiscrete.
If X is infinite, then $T_2$ is discrete because for
x in X, {x} is open since X - {x} is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

The only way for $T_{1}$ to be a topology is if $T_{X}$ and/or $T_{Y}$ is the trivial topology. Anything else doesn't work.

The only way for $T_{2}$ to be a topology is if $X$ is finite.